# JMeter output result during sample running

Tags: jmeter

I am writing a JSR223 sample that simulate an SSE client.
Something like that:

```
import com.ssetest.*
String resp="";

EventHandler eventHandler = eventText -> {
  log.info(eventText);
  resp=resp + eventText + "\n";
    SampleResult.setResponseData(resp,"866");
};

SSEClient sseClient = SSEClient.builder().url("http://localhost:3000/sse").eventHandler(eventHandler)
      .build();
      
sseClient.start();

sleep(10000);

sseClient.shutdown();
SampleResult.setResponseCode("200");
```

I would like to be able to see the output in the result data tab as messages are coming from the server and not only when the sample complete the execution.

Is it possible to achieve this behavior in JMeter?

Maybe using a custom JSR223 listener that listen to a variable that is getting changed in my JSR223 sampler?

Answer (score 1):

As per [JMeter 5.4.](https://lists.apache.org/thread/dbg1bxywcwx5vtdwqf8ownf7ppgqjn41)3 it's not possible, the result is being sent to GUI, [Listeners](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html) and to the [.jtl file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles) as soon as the Sampler is finished

If you want to see the progress during SSE client execution you can:

- use `OUT.println('something')` to print the incoming messages to [STDOUT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_(stdout))
- use `log.info('something')` to print the incoming messages to [jmeter.log](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging)

You can take a look at [How to Load Test SSE Services with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-load-test-sse-services-with-jmeter) to learn how to handle `onMessage()` event so you could print each incoming message